# W/ActivityThread: handleWindowVisibility: no activity for token android.os.BinderProxy@6c3e2b4

Tags: android, android-fragmentactivity

I try to run an activity after taping a button, but instead of the activity I expected to have, a blank activity runs. The logcat indicates :

```
W/ActivityThread: handleWindowVisibility: no activity for token android.os.BinderProxy@6c3e2b4
```

and I do not understand that.

BuildingActivity.java

```java
public class BuildingActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Building mBuilding;
    private BaseAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_building);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

        FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                //        .setAction("Action", null).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent(BuildingActivity.this.getApplication(), AddBase.class);
                BuildingActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
...
```

AddBase.java

```java
public class AddBase extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }
}
```

AddBaseFragment.java

```java
public class AddBaseFragment extends Fragment {

    private AddBaseViewModel mViewModel;

    public static AddBaseFragment newInstance() {
        return new AddBaseFragment();
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                             @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_add_base, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        mViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(AddBaseViewModel.class);
        // TODO: Use the ViewModel
    }

}
```

What I don't understand is that it seems to work (displaying the activity correctly) in some of my teams device, but not in mine. So I thought it was a build/clear issue, but none of these worked :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems Like you did not called setContentView() inside the onCreate() of your AddBase Activity.

Comment: Yes, that was it ! Thanks !

Comment: happy coding :)